# set timeout giving not the desired result

Tags: javascript, jquery

here my function with setTimout call just immedieatly after the click but i wants it to fire ater 10 sec of click

```
$('#switchsubjects').click(function(e)
{
    i++;
var x=$('#subject-class-switch').html();
    if(i<2)
    {
        $(this).append('<ul id="dcl"><li class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">Class</li><li class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">Subjects</li></ul>');
            e.stopPropagation();
    setTimeout(rm(),10000);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#dcl').remove();
        i=0;
    }
});     

        function rm()
        {
        console.log("working");
        $('#dcl').remove();
        i=0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(rm ,10000);  // note no parentheses after rm
```

The `setTimeout()` function expects the first parameter to be a function reference (or a string, but a string is almost always the wrong choice). By saying `rm()` you were actually calling the `rm` function at that point and passing its return value to `setTimeout()` (in this case the return value is `undefined`). If you pass `rm` without the parentheses that passes a reference to your function that `setTimeout` can then call after the delay you specify.

[The doco at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) is pretty good for more information and other examples.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't understand the difference between a function call and a function reference. Let's say you have this function

```
function myFunction() {
   // some code
}
```

Then this is an immediate function call

```
myFunction()
```

And this is a function reference

```
myFunction
```

setTimeout's first parameter has to be a function reference (or a string containing javascript code, but this is deprecated).

```
setTimeout(rm, 10000);
```

Comment: ...or a variable containing a string - doesn't have to be a literal.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout("rm()",10000);
```

Otherwise `rm()`is executed immediatly, and only its results is evaluated 10s later.